# Joining Two CTE's with Pivots

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

This is going to be a long one so i'm very sorry. I had a search and i could find anything that fit the bill for the fault I'm having.

I currently need to figure out how to join two CTE's which both are pivoted to allow for the data to be stitched back into a table.

Unfortunately I can't get the tables updated to be in the correct format required as the data has to be maintained in its original design for auditing purposes.

Currently the CTES's are

**CTE1 Files:**

- ID
- REF
- UserID
- SubmitDate
- SubmitBy
- a1
- a2
- a3
- a4
- a5
- comments

**CTE2 Fields:**

- ID
- q1
- q2
- q3
- q4
- q5

The thought is to do the join off the ID Field on both CTE's 1 and 2 
However I am struggling to get the join to work.

**Structure of the Join Logic**

```
WITH CTE1 as 
(
    ** CTE QUERY **
),
CTE2 AS 
(
    ** CTE QUERY **
)

Select
 *
FROM
        CTE1
JOIN    CTE2    on CTE1.id = CTE2.id
```

I believe that this could potentially be due to the complex CTE used to separate a value from the table. The CTE's are extremely similar to a previous post i made ( [Splitting Strings with Regular Terms to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800093/splitting-strings-with-regular-terms-to-columns) ) which the data is pivoted *(will include below)*

**Expected Return**

[image]

Thanks for any help. Also if you require additional information and i'll include.

Currently It doesn't return anything I receive the following error message

```
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 61
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

Comment: what is the current result and please tag the RDBMS involved

Comment: Can you please paste entire code so that some one can parse and check

Comment: Uploaded TheGameisWar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your query is incorrect.

It has to be something like this:

```
WITH 
CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
)
,CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
)
,CTE3 AS 
(
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
)
,CTE4 AS 
(
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
)
SELECT ...
FROM ...
;
```

But you have something like this:

```
WITH 
CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
)
SELECT ...
FROM ...
,CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
)
SELECT ...
FROM ...
SELECT ...
FROM ...
;
```

I hope you see the difference.

`WITH` should be followed be several CTEs followed by a single final `SELECT`. You can't have standalone `SELECT` in the middle of the query without wrapping it into a CTE.

Comment: Hi Mate, Thanks for that I can see what your saying. The problem is the data is now pretty fragmented on that select statement at the end is it possible to pivot on two separate levels.

Comment: @Merenix, sorry, trying to actually understand what your queries do is a very different question. Sort out the basic syntax problems and then try to ask another question. Show some sample data that reproduces the problem, show what result you expect, show how results of your current query differ from the expected result.

Comment: Dont say sorry mate, youre trying to help me. Last thing you should be saying is sorry. Good news is I got it returning how i expected.  This Query has been the nightmare scenario because we couldn't impliment the right solutions. Thanks again mate. +1 and accepted the vote. Almost tempted to put bounty on it and accept again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should start as ;WITH 
You have missed ';' may be that is an issue